# Cordova 7.1.0 cannot build ionic android project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-android

cordova android has some issues and not sure how to solve it.

I have updated my cordova to the latest `cordova@7.1.0` and my node to `node8.2.0`

but each time i try to build my ionic cordova project i get two errors

when i try to build my android project ionic cordova platform add android

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
```

Also when i try to run ionic cordova prepare i get the following error

```
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/platforms/browser/cordova/Api.js'
Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "browser" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. browser not supported.)
```

Kinda confused on these two errors and not sure how to solve them.

I am building an Ionic3 project.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you find an answer?